# Outputting text to keyboard with touchesBegan in Swift

Tags: ios, uibutton, keyboard, swift, touchesbegan

I am creating a custom keyboard for practise and I am trying to use touchesBegan/Moved/Ended instead of typical UIButton control events as it is necessary in my project. 
For now I am trying to simply output some text when one of my buttons' frame contains the touched point, as can be seen below:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    var touchPoint: UITouch = touches.anyObject() as UITouch


    if CGRectContainsPoint(button01.frame, touchPoint.locationInView(self.view))  {

          var output = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

          output.insertText(button01.outputText)


        }        
}
```

Cant figure out why this isn't working, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have played around a little and it seems that the touchesBegan isn't even firing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I set the buttons' userInteractionEnabled to false, so that the touches would actually be registered by the view instead of being eaten up by the UIButton on top. Hope this will help another person.